# How to write object tags to s3 using Mule?

Tags: amazon-s3, mule, mulesoft, mule-connector

I need to write tags to s3 objects I create using Mule with the create object operation of the S3 connector.

Any way where I can pass the tags? The fields mentioned in the S3 create object operation doesn't have one. Do I need to pass it in user data? There is a field called ETag. But I presume that is different from object tag.

Comment: MuleSoft is the name of the company. Mule is the name of their product that runs integrations.